# SpeechStarted/SpeechCompleted events being delayed indefinitely

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have a program that switches on a relay when the synthesis engine starts speaking, and turns it off when it finishes speaking. On the PC that I am compiling/working on, it works fine, 100% of the time. Engine starts talking, event is raised, relay is turned on, engine stops talking, event is raised, relay is turned off. No problems. Simple!

When I put the program on any of my laptops, the events are not raised immediately. The program will speak several prompts, and eventually all of the events will be raised in short order. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to this delay. One time it was a few seconds, usually it's over a minute. Sometimes the events aren't raised at all (or they aren't raised soon enough for me to see...)

This happens both with the published application and in the debug environment in VS2013, but only on my laptops. Main PC is Win8, one laptop is Win8, and other laptops are Win7. My main PC and win8 laptop are nearly identical as far as environment goes.

I don't even know where to start with troubleshooting this. I have verified (I think) that the event itself is not being raised by simply outputting some text to console, with zero conditions, anytime it's raised. After a few minutes, I will usually get a flood of events in the console.

I was thinking that MAYBE it's a performance issue (though none of these laptops are underpowered whatsoever) but I don't really know how to confirm that, or how I would alleviate it. Put the whole TTS engine, including events, in its own thread? Is that even possible or practical? There shouldn't really be any issues with the program slowing down or getting stuck and somehow delaying the event - there's almost nothing else going on.

Below is the relevant code, with most unrelated stuff stripped.

```
    TTS.SpeakStarted += new EventHandler<SpeakStartedEventArgs>(TTS_SpeakStarted);
    TTS.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(TTS_SpeakCompleted);


    void TTS_SpeakStarted(object sender, SpeakStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.relay_enabled)
                // do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
    }
    void TTS_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.relay_enabled)
                // do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the SpeakStarted/SpeakCompleted events to function properly.

My first attempt at a solution was to put my speak method in it's own thread, and change it to speak synchronously. That way I could have my before-code, and then speak which would block until finished, and then my after code. This did not work either. Speak would block for the same indefinite amount of time as it took to raise the events, so while my before-code would execute, my after-code would not.

My solution in the end was to use the StateChanged event instead of SpeakStarted/SpeakCompleted. For some reason, the StateChanged event functioned fine, and I was able to use the State to determine when the engine had begun speaking, and when it was "ready", presumed finished speaking.